# How to make image slider similar to Ola app

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I want to make an **image slider** like used in **ola app** but I have no idea about it.
The background image of slider seems to be same for all the slides . Kindly tell me how I can do that.
[image: Ola Image slider]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: try this https://github.com/sushildlh/Slide

Comment: @sushildlh thanks. but My main concern is that backgroud image that is floating and also on opening of app car movement . can you help in that?

Comment: May you plaesae visit the Ola app for clear idea what I want.

Comment: hello have u got answer please help me if you get proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code and search CircleIndicator lib and use it,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  CircleIndicator mPageIndicator;
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();

viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 mPageIndicator.setViewPager(mViewpager);

 }


private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private int[] mImages = new int[] {
    R.drawable.chiang_mai,
    R.drawable.himeji,
    R.drawable.petronas_twin_tower,
    R.drawable.ulm
};

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return mImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
  return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  Context context = MainActivity.this;
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
  int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
      R.dimen.padding_medium);
  imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
  imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
  ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
  return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}}
```

Comment: thanks. but My main concern is that backgroud image that is floating and also on opening of app car movement . can you help in that?

Comment: May you plaesae visit the Ola app for clear idea what I want.

Comment: HI,Can you please refer this link  https://github.com/paolorotolo/AppIntro

Comment: If you canot understand above code,Otherwise i'll help you.